# Strict convexity of real function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $\Phi:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be the function defined by $\Phi(t) = ((1-t)^p+\theta\cdot t^p)^{1/p}$ for every $t\in[0,1]$, with $\theta\in (0,\infty)$ being a fixed real positive number and $1<p<\infty$.

My question is whether or not $\Phi$ is a strictly convex function. I am stuck in that question. I have tried to compute the first and second derivatives and study if they are monotone, but I don't know if it is the correct way.

Comment: And what is $p$?

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro I am sorry, we have that $1<p<\infty$.

Comment: To the strict convexity of a twice differentiable function it is equivalent that the first derivative is strictly increasing. To this it is  equivalent that the second derivative is strictly positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: error in derivatives**

Since $\Phi(t):[0,1]\to (0,\infty]$ is twice differentiable in its domain, then we can analyze the sign of its second derivative (why?). We have:

$$\Phi'(t)=(-(1 - t)^{-1 + p} + \theta t^{-1 + p}) ((1 - t)^p + \theta t^p)^{-1 + p^{-1}},$$

$$\Phi''(t)=(-1 + p) (-t(-1 + t) )^{-2 + p} \theta ((1 - t)^p + t^p \theta)^{-2 + p^{-1}}.$$

Notice that indeed $\Phi(t)''>0$ for $t\in(0,1)$ but $\Phi''(0)=\Phi''(1)=0$. Is this what you obtained? I checked them with Wolfram [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%281-t%29%5Ep%2Btheta%20t%5Ep%29%5E%7B1%2Fp%7D) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-%281%20-%20t%29%5E%28-1%20%2B%20p%29%20%2B%20t%5E%28-1%20%2B%20p%29%20%CE%B8%29%20%28%281%20-%20t%29%5Ep%20%2B%20t%5Ep%20%CE%B8%29%5E%28-1%20%2B%20p%5E%28-1%29%29%20).

Comment: This $\Phi''(t)$ looks more like $\Phi'(t)$ to me. Even if I should be wrong in that point: when $t$ is close to to zero then $\theta>0$ cannot imply that condition $\theta>(1/t-1)^{-1+p}.$

Comment: ooops, yeah copied the wrong one- be back soon :)